# How can I filter array according to another array in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, searchbar

I have search bar and its search order ids in my table view in that point I have another array which have some datas according to their order ids. My search bar working correctly, filtered array working correct but other array didn't work. (order ids and order contents have conflicts) The order of orders is shifting. How can I connect these two arrays? 
Here my code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: sipCellId, for: indexPath) as! sipCell

    if isSearching {
        searched = filteredArray[indexPath.row]


    }else{
        searched = self.orderId[indexPath.row]

    }


     cell.orderIdLabel.text = searched
     cell.detailLabel.text =  self.newDatas[indexPath.row]



     return cell

}
```

Here my search bar functions:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if mainSearchBar.text == nil || mainSearchBar.text == "" {
        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }else {
        isSearching = true
        filteredArray = orderId.filter({$0.range(of: mainSearchBar.text!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil})

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is *another array*?

Comment: I see 3 arrays in the code, filteredArray, orderId and newDatas but I have no idea which 2 you mean and what you mean by conflicts. You need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

The context of your question is not clear enough you should clarify more, but generally speaking if you want to filter the original array according to another array's elements (per your headline question) you can simply filter the original array and ask if the other array contains the element.

```
originalArray = originalArray.filter{otherArray.contains($0)}
```